# Re-use an overlayed image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Basically I had two images which I overlayed using control point registration; the final part of the code is :

```
[registered2, xdata, ydata] = imtransform(unregistered1, tform,...
                                        'FillValues', 255);

figure; imshow(registered2, 'XData', xdata, 'YData', ydata)


hold on

imshow(unregistered);

ylim = get(gca, 'YLim');

set(gca, 'YLim', [0.5 ylim(2)])

set(gca,'XLim',[0 7000])
```

I want to further use this final image (dont need to save it). Like;

```
cpselect(final_image_from_above, new_unregistered_image)
```

However, i have tried `getframe()`, `saveas()`, etc. But the problem with that was the quality of the image gets very bad.

Thanks,

Comment: Define 'quality of the image', or show an example.

Comment: something like that:

http://www.radvision.com/NR/rdonlyres/34FD8C64-2FD9-421A-8966-1CE6A7F75C26/0/Good_Bad.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should better operate the images in the matrix domain, i.e., consider them as matrix (mxnx3) and perform the overlapping. Then you can obtain the final image as a matrice. Its quality will be good.